# Friendly challenge - alternate solutions for simplifying $\int \frac{x+1}{x-1} \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, recreational-mathematics

I have a habit of more or less "making up" problems and trying to solve them in my free time. This particular one I found to be fun, and thought others might enjoy trying to solve it using other means. Have fun, enjoy and feel free to post your solutions/suggestions.

Here is my solution:
$\int \frac{x+1}{x-1} \, dx$ =
$\int \frac{x}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-1} \,dx$ =
$\int \frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x-1} +1 \,dx$ =
$\int \frac{2}{x-1} + 1 \,dx$ =
$2ln|x-1|+x+C $

Comment: What do you consider as a normal solution and what do you consider as an alternate solution?

Comment: I raise you $2\ln|x-1|+x+C+D\,\text{sgn}(x-1)$.

Comment: @Alain Remillard: Maybe the $u$-substitution given by $u = x-1$?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro we could also make a kind of trigonometric substitution with $x = \cos^2 t$

Comment: @Alain Remillard: For what it's worth, the $u = x - 1$ substitution is what one would (ordinarily; probably other methods can be used) do if the two additive terms of $x-1$ were "algebraically trapped" inside of something like a square root or a cube root, such as $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$ or $\frac{x+1}{\sqrt[3]{x-1}}$ or $\frac{x+1}{{(x-1)}^{5/3}}.$

Comment: @AlainRemillard you have to be careful with such substitutions: the domain of $x$ in the original integral and the range of $\cos^2 t$ are quite different.

Comment: @UmbertoP. you are right. To be honest, I haven't tried it, I was just looking for a "funny" alternate way to solve it.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro the $x = \cos^2 t$ is not what we would think of first, but it could still help if the denominator was trap in a root since $\cos^2 t - 1 = \sin^2 t$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{x+1}{x-1}dx=\int\left(1+\dfrac2{x-1}\right)dx=x+2\ln\mid x-1\mid+\,C$$

Comment: Truly a stroke of genius, I have to say :D

Comment: Should be $x+2\ln|x-1|+C$.

Comment: I edited, changing () to ||, and I answered before OP gave a solution in the question